# django как добавить пользователю права?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я гуглил, искал в книге, но так и не нашел, как добавлять пользователям права. Я в шоке.

Вот допустим я хочу страницу, при переходе на которую пользователю будут выдоватся какие-либо права.

Что-то типо такого:

```
request.user.add_perm("Article.add_Article")
```

только метода add_perm нету, и мне нужна замена ему.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361273/5909792 ?

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот вопрос там может быть нужная вам информация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361235/django-set-user-permissions-when-user-is-automatically-created-using-get-or-cr

Comment: @dragonsSTREAMING вы скинули тоже самое, что и предыдущий комментатор)